# Custom page number Kaminari gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari

I am using Kaminari gem with my rails 3.2 application. Its working fine. Now i want to add a custom page number text field where user can provide a page number and by hitting return key should load the required page number. What is the best approach to implement this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Each of the result pages differ in the parameter used for `page`.

Eg: If the main url is http://www.my_site.com/my_list, the urls for the various pages would look as follows:

- First page: http://www.my_site.com/my_list
- Second page: http://www.my_site.com/my_list?page=2
- Third page: http://www.my_site.com/my_list?page=3
- ...

So you just need to set `page=params[:required_page_number]` to get the right page.